# Paypal Recurring/Subscription integration issues

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing

I want to integrate Paypal Recurring Payment, so that I can get Payment from my customers on regular basis, I checked there are several methods,

1. Paypal Subscription Button `(xclick-subscriptions)`

   In this method, I tried both Hosted and Non-hosted buttons, But I don't want that user redirects on Paypal completely (Paypal should open in Browser window or Popup), 
   How can I achieve this?
2. Paypal NVP/SOAP API

   I tried this API with `checkout.js`, but it is deprecated now, don't want to use it any more,

   **EDIT**: also I can created agreement with Payment Payment method, but when tried to pay with Credit Card, it shows me `DPRP is disabled for this merchant`, after a lot of research i found that for Card, *Payment Pro* must be enabled for merchant account, and it costs around *$30-35/month*, don't want to Pay this much amount,
3. Paypal Billing Plan and Agreement API

   I tried this API, and faced the same issue just like the NVP/SOAP API (`DPRP is disabled for this merchant`)
4. Paypal Payflow

   I tried this API, It provide a different login called *Paypal Manager*, But when I tried to complete my profile, but it is asking $10 for enable Recurring/Subscription Payment,

Apart from above these, You can suggest me good method which suites my
requirement.

Comment: Where are you seeing that checkout.js is deprecated?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, but i wanna say that `Paypal NVP/SOAP API` is deprecated i am just using the `checkout.js` with the same.

Comment: They have the NVP/SOAP APIs labeled as deprecated, but the fact is they aren't going away any time soon, if ever.  I still use them primarily myself because I find them easier to use and they have features that the REST API simply doesn't have yet.  There are way too many people using those APIs for them to kill them.  If they'll do what you want I'd recommend just go that route.  Again, I still use them primarily myself.

Comment: I am facing the same issue `DPRP is disabled for this merchant` with NVP/SOAP API

Comment: As you already noted, that means Payments Pro (DoDirectPayment) with Recurring Payments is not active on the account.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to pay this much amount every month, so please let me know, if there is any other way?

Comment: Does it **need** to be paypal? [Stripe](https://stripe.com/gb) offer good subscription routines with an awesome API. It's also available in Canada and I think the transaction fees are similar if not better to PayPal with no monthly costs.

Comment: sorry @webnoob, our client only requires paypal recurring payments.

Comment: Well, I think you're going to have to ask your client to pay the money PayPal are expecting in that case.

Comment: Please check 1st point of question (Paypal Subscription Button), Can we achieve this?

Comment: Setting `target="_blank"` on the **FORM** tag should do that for you.

Comment: But its not a perfect solution which I want, `target="_blank"` only opens in new tab, I want to open in child window instead, like we did in incontext integration,

Comment: That is handled in the browser, you can't control that. Another option is to have the user click on something to open a new popup window and then have them click on the paypal button. It could be within an iframe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162345/discussion-between-vijay-dohare-and-webnoob).

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can get or the product that available for Recurring Payment for the merchant in India is the option 1 (Paypal Subscription Button (xclick-subscriptions) and option 3 (). But option 3, it needs to be specific.

Option 3 only allowed if you set the payment_method = paypal and not credit_card.

As far as i know, the option 2 using checkout.js are not compatible yet with Recurring Payment.

Comment: No, My client is from Canada, So please suggest me for country Canada, which suites my requirement,